# Ligatures in Philokalia font

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, ligatures

At CTAN there is a package called `philokalia`. I am trying to use [OTF font from it](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/philokalia) in LuaLaTeX, but I cannot get the ligatures.

M(n)WE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{philokalia}

\begin{document}
\fontencoding{EU1}
\fontfamily{plk}
\selectfont
Εἰς πολλά ἔτη, Δέσποτα!

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Philokalia}
Εἰς πολλά ἔτη, Δέσποτα!
\end{document}
```

Here what comes as result from XeLaTeX:
[image: Eis polla eth, Despota!]

LuaLaTeX is able to compile only second row of text same way (unligatured λλ), giving an error `Encoding scheme EU1 unknown.`

Can I get the ligatures without the package, just through `\setmainfont`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package is too old to know about EU2, the encoding of luatex. You can get the ligatures by selecting the Historic set:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Greek,Ligatures=TeX,Ligatures={Historic}]{Philokalia}
\begin{document}
Εἰς πολλά ἔτη, Δέσποτα! ---
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In the almost ten years since the `philokalia` package has been released, several things have changed in the XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX world.

Here is a working setup, with the same example as in the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\setmainfont{Philokalia}[
  %Renderer=OpenType,
  Script=Greek,
  Ligatures=Historic,
]
\newfontfamily{\PHtitl}{Philokalia}[
  %Renderer=OpenType,
  Script=Greek,
  Style=TitlingCaps,
  Scale=0.4,
]

\setmainlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\PHtitl}
\renewcommand{\LettrineTestString}{ΑΒΓΔ}

\begin{document}

Εἰς πολλά ἔτη, Δέσποτα!

\lettrine[lines=3]{Π}{ερὶ} ποιητικῆς αὐτῆς τε καὶ τῶν εἰδῶν αὐτῆς, 
ἥν τινα δύναμιν ἕκαστον ἔχει, καὶ πῶς δεῖ συνίστασθαι τοὺς μύθους εἰ μέλλει 
καλῶς ἕξειν ἡ ποίησις, ἔτι δὲ ἐκ πόσων καὶ ποίων ἐστὶ μορίων, ὁμοίως δὲ καὶ 
περὶ τῶν ἄλλων ὅσα τῆς αὐτῆς ἐστι μεθόδου, λέγωμεν ἀρξάμενοι κατὰ φύσιν 
πρῶτον ἀπὸ τῶν πρώτων.

Ἐποποιία δὴ καὶ ἡ τῆς τραγῳδίας ποίησις ἔτι δὲ κωμῳδία καὶ ἡ διθυραμβοποιητικὴ 
καὶ τῆς αὐλητικῆς ἡ πλείστη καὶ κιθαριστικῆς πᾶσαι τυγχάνουσιν οὖσαι μιμήσεις 
τὸ σύνολον· διαφέρουσι δὲ ἀλλήλων τρισίν, ἢ γὰρ τῷ ἐν ἑτέροις μιμεῖσθαι ἢ τῷ 
ἕτερα ἢ τῷ ἑτέρως καὶ μὴ τὸν αὐτὸν τρόπον. 

Ὥσπερ γὰρ καὶ χρώμασι καὶ σχήμασι πολλὰ μιμοῦνταί τινες ἀπεικάζοντες (οἱ 
μὲν [20] διὰ τέχνης οἱ δὲ διὰ συνηθείας), ἕτεροι δὲ διὰ τῆς φωνῆς, οὕτω κἀν 
ταῖς εἰρημέναις τέχναις ἅπασαι μὲν ποιοῦνται τὴν μίμησιν ἐν ῥυθμῷ καὶ λόγῳ καὶ
ἁρμονίᾳ, τούτοις δ᾽ ἢ χωρὶς ἢ μεμιγμένοις· οἷον ἁρμονίᾳ μὲν καὶ ῥυθμῷ χρώμεναι 
μόνον ἥ τε αὐλητικὴ καὶ ἡ κιθαριστικὴ κἂν εἴ τινες [25] ἕτεραι τυγχάνωσιν οὖσαι 
τοιαῦται τὴν δύναμιν, οἷον ἡ τῶν συρίγγων, αὐτῷ δὲ τῷ ῥυθμῷ [μιμοῦνται] χωρὶς 
ἁρμονίας ἡ τῶν ὀρχηστῶν (καὶ γὰρ οὗτοι διὰ τῶν σχηματιζομένων ῥυθμῶν μιμοῦνται 
καὶ ἤθη καὶ πάθη καὶ πράξεις)· 

\end{document}
```

[image]